# Deferred loading of Twitter Tooltip (or any other JavaScript)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Twitter Bootstrap's Tooltip working:

```
$("[rel=popover]")
    .popover()
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    });
```

This works on HTML. However, I have JavaScript that generates some code. How can I use `jQuery.on()` or `delegate()` to get this to work with deferred JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', "[rel=popover]", function() {
   $(this).popover()
})
```

Comment: i believe the popover() function is only to be called once - and sets up the events nessesary for the plugin to work.